# Editing a specific cell with Pandas [Python]

Tags: python, pandas

I am having a problem with Pandas, have looked everywhere but think I am overlooking something.

I have a csv file I import to pandas, which has a ID column and another column I will call Column 2. I want to: 
1. Input an ID to python. 
2. Search this ID in the ID column with Pandas, and put a 1 on the adjacent cell, in Column 2.

```
import pandas

csvfile = pandas.read_csv('document1.csv')

#Convert everything to string for simplicity
csvfile['ID'] = csvfile['ID'].astype(str)

#Fill in all missing NaN
csvfile = csvfile.fillna('missing')

#looking for the row in which the ID '10099870.0' is in. 
indexid = csvfile.loc[csvfile['ID'] == '10099870.0'].index

# Important part! I think this selects the column 2, row 'indexid' and replaces missing with 1. 
csvfile['Column 2'][indexid].replace('missing', '1')
```

I know this is a simple question but thanks for all your help!

Mauricio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I'd do:

```
cond = csvfile.ID == '10099870.0'
col = 'Column 2'
csvfile.loc[cond, col] = csvfile.loc[cond, col].replace('missing', '1')
```

Comment: I did, thanks! However I got this message (I've got to keep posting/helping!): Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks again piRSquared